# undirected acyclic graph edge insertion

Tags: algorithm

Is there any algorithm that inserts a node in undirected graph iff graph is acyclic?

for example:
if graph is like below

```
0 - 1
|
2 - 3
4 - 5
```

valid insertion : 2-4

```
0 - 1
|
2 - 3
|
4 - 5
```

invalid insertion : 1 - 3

```
0 - 1
|   |   <=== cyclic!!!
2 - 3
4 - 5
```

If there is any example code with c++, I would really appreciate.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: Inserts a node where and how? Explain which insertions are valid and which are not.

Comment: You can run BFS from an arbitrary vertex. Any time you run out of reachable vertices, form an edge between an arbitrary reached vertex and unreachable vertex, and continue BFS. Repeat until you run out of unreachable vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for the set of vertices. This structure has the following operations:

- `find(x)` to return the identifier of the set where `x` belongs,
- `union(x,y)` to merge the sets of `x` and `y`.

1. Start with a set for the each vertex.
2. Before adding an edge, check whether its ends are in the same set.
3. If not, add the edge and merge the corresponding sets.

For your example, the state of the data structure is the following:

- S1 = {0,1,2,3}
- S2 = {4,5}

When you try to add an edge 1-3, you get that vertices 1 and 3 belong to the same set S1, so you skip adding.

When you try to add an edge 2-4, you get that vertices 2 and 4 belong to the different sets (S1 and S2, correspondingly), you add this edge, and update the structure to be:

- S1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Thank you for explanation and the wiki link!! Now I should try implementation of this idea. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer suits your needs, it is appropriate to mark it as accepted.